# JMeter read file to array

Tags: arrays, csv, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I am trying to read these items from .csv file to array separating variables by comma or dot.

[image]

I would like to get:

http://www.example.com/GH001.GH002.KL003.KL010.json

Any ideas?

I tried using Bean Shell PreProcessor, but it doesn't work.

```
String Articles = "${__StringFromFile(C:\docs\loadtest\articles.csv,,,)}";

String[] Articles1 = Articles.split(",");

vars.put("Articles1",Articles1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would suggest switching to Groovy.

The relevant code would be something like:

```
def lines = new File('C:/docs/loadtest/articles.csv').readLines()
def articles = new String()
lines.each { line ->
    articles += line += '.'
}

vars.put('Articles1',articles);
```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information, benchmarks, tips and tricks.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriT ! I use ${Articles1} to call the variable in HTTP, but it doesn' return the products from file... I get  
www.products.${Articles1}.html